# Sliding Frameless Shower over tub installation

Tags: shower, sliding-glass-door

We are trying to install a frameless shower glass over our acrylic tub. After drilling a hole for the bar that goes from left to right, there is no stud on the right side. However, the right side is where the fixed panel will be installed, there is a stud available for the 2 hinges. The question is, are we able to use an anchor on one side of the bar and still be secure?

Comment: A couple of pictures or a sketch of your situation would be helpful. Also, knowing what your walls are made out of (drywall/cement board over studs? poured concrete? cinder block? other?) will help as well. That said, there are all sorts of wall anchors (use the type for your wall) that are capable of supporting 100's of pounds. This isn't the moving side, but, if it's attached to the moving parts, you may want to go "overkill" with the anchors for a few bucks more, just to be sure.

Comment: Freeman: We actually didn't have any studs. The builder built the enclosure directly to the studs and no drywall behind it. As you recommend, we are placing heavy duty anchors in each hole.

Comment: If you mean that you're anchoring the shower door directly to the acrylic shower surround, I'm not sure that's a good idea! I can't imagine that those are going to bear much weight at all. Frankly, that sounds like a really Bad Idea™ to me. If there's no drywall, is there at least some horizontal blocking you could attach things to? What's on the other side? It might be worth opening that wall up to take a look and/or add some blocking for you to attach the shower doors to.